# Unable to wrap labels of buttons inside Material Button Toggle Group

Tags: android, xml, button, android-wrap-content, materialbutton

I have three buttons inside a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`. The issue is that **all the labels are being cut off and not wrapped**.

[image: Screenshot of the layout]

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggle_pomo_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pomo_card"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_pomo"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/class_time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_short_break"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/short_break" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_long_break"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/long_break" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any proper solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't wrap them in a single line because the measured width of the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` view is declared as limited and therefore it decides to ellipsize them at the end. You can verify that if you used a wider screen or landscape mode where the text would wrap if it is still within the allowed width.

Removing the buttons horizontal padding `android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"` would make a little room.

But you could do that in two lines programmatically; as `android:maxLength` property doesn't work for a bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792884/android-adding-a-button-with-multiline-text-inside-materialbuttontogglegroup-doe):

```
val bt_pomo= findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_pomo)
bt_pomo.maxLines = 2
```

And repeat that for the other two buttons